# Error using rtcwake: unable to find device

Tags: 18.04, suspend, wakeup, rtc

I like to run rtcwake to wake up my machine automatically from suspend after some time using this command

```
$ sudo rtcwake -u -s 60 -m mem
```

But I get the following error:

```
rtcwake: /dev/rtc0: unable to find device: No such file or directory
```

Is there a way to fix this issue or are there any alternatives to using `rtcwake`?
I have a Thinkpad X1 Carbon Gen 7 machine.